# CSS Menu central alignment

Tags: css, menu, alignment

I am trying to create a menu using CSS, but I have a problem with its actual placement.

Right now, no matter what I tried it is always on the left side of the screen and not stretched. I would like to have it in the center and possibly stretch to 100% of the screen. I tried changing the width parameter, margins, text-align, but I always got something different than I wanted or it didnt work at all.

The menu can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/98tW6/10/

As I said, all I want is to have it in the center top of the page and possibly stretched so that the background image repeats all over the screen at the top with the buttons in the center.

I think the crucial lines are within this part of the code:

```
div#menu
```

but I am not sure

Comment: Like this you mean? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/98tW6/11/).

Comment: thanks. partly... it is stretched as I wanted it, but I wanted the buttons to stay next to each other like before, just have a blank red piece to the right and left equally if you understand what I mean. Center it and stretch just the background image on both sides

Answer (score 1):

Remove float and add this to the `<ul>`:

```
width:100%;
text-align:center;
```

Then remove the float from the `<li>` items and make them `inline-block` elements, because they are `inline-block` now they will respond to the `text-align:center` of the parent, and will be centered:

```
display: inline-block;
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/98tW6/17/

Comment: oops, but Im just looking, try hovering over the last items on the menu, it is somehow weird

Comment: @user2678541 If you have another question, please make a new post.

Comment: the problem is.. try extending it in jsfiddle, so that the preview window covers most of the page horizontally. and you will se it doesnt work then

Comment: @user2678541 It's because your background image is not big enough, you can set no-repeat to repeat and you will see that it cover's up the enitire space

Comment: thanks, but still, look at the submenus. Try hovering down right till the last item, the ones that do not expand are displayed incorrectly.